# What is a word for someone who prefers to be lonely?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that means someone isn't a people's person, someone who feels much more comfortable without the need of friends or family and keeps to themselves.

Example: I have a talent in music and drawing. There's tons of instrumentals I want to put words to. I'm also trying to hone my skills to draw free-handed which will take a significant amount of time. And as if the dozens of anime series I haven't finished watching wasn't bad enough; in addition there are a great number of other TV shows  that I want to catch up on. I don't have the time for nor the inclination to lead  a busy social life.

In short, "I'm sort of a ________. You could say, I've got too much on my plate".

Comment: There exists the word *loner* but it carries very negative overtones.

Comment: A neighbour on a motor scooter called out to me "Hey, Ringo, are you a 'cluse?" So, 'cluse is now official Hereford dialect for a recluse who spends half the night poring over books and screens.

Comment: The answers are all over the map, clearly indicating that the question is not clear. What is the part of speech you are after? What is the context, domain, and register? Where is your example sentence? Is it even a good thing or a bad thing? A good thing or a bad thing considered by whom? What words have you got so far, but rejected, and for what reasons? Give us something, anything, to work with.

Comment: "These  answers are all over the map"?.Can't you see that all of these answers sound the same .Hermit sounds closes to me but I want to see more possible ideas.I didn't reject anything. You seem to have mistaken reject with the fact I prefer alot of answers.Haven't ever heard the qoute"the more the barrier".

Comment: You may use **unsociable** or **nongregarious**

Comment: Introvert? They need a lot of alone time.

Comment: Yes, definitely **introvert**.  There's a great Ted talk about being introverted: https://www.ted.com/speakers/susan_cain  ---  An introvert recharges by spending time alone.  ---  Please remove "food" from your last sentence.  It should be "I have a lot on my plate."  (But actually, I don't think this sentence will help people understand why you crave solitude.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt C'mon, the question is clear. It's got far more context than 75% of all SWRs I've seen. And that's a fact.

Comment: it should be: "...prefers to be **alone**" Instead "a lonely person" is someone who feels alone and sad, a person who has no friends but would like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Hermit**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hermit) as "A reclusive or solitary person.".

Comment: An hermit has withdrawn from society and lives a solitary existence.

Comment: Based on the Cambridge dictionary it is defined as "a person who lives alone and apart from the rest of society, especially for religious reasons". So, I think it doesn't fit OP .

Comment: Oxford dictionary: a person who, usually for religious reasons, lives a very simple life alone and does not meet or talk to other people

Answer (score 5):

A **loner** (*noun*):

A person that prefers not to associate with others

> '*my interest in birdwatching had made me a bit of a loner*'

**self-contained** (*adj.*):

(Of a person) quiet and independent; not depending on or influenced by others

> '*I can look after myself better than most people; I'm self contained.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I don't know if you have enough rep, but if you liked the question and believe it is on-topic, you can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Hi @Mari-LouA I found I can vote to reopen, so have done so. Thanks for pointing the option out to me.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the word **[recluse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/recluse)** defined by Oxford dictionary as:

> **recluse** *(noun)*
>
> A person who lives a solitary life and tends to avoid other people.

*'He seems to be somewhat of a recluse, he rarely goes out on the weekends and tends to shy away from new people.'*

Answer (score 3):

My favourite term for such a person is [***lone wolf***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_wolf_%28trait%29).

This originates in the animal realm: a lone wolf is one that left the pack and is obliged to provide for itself. However, it applies to persons who live or act alone, as well.

Comment: I don't know if you have enough rep, but if you liked the question and believe it is on-topic, you can vote to reopen it

Answer (score 2):

You could call that person a *solitary* individual.

From TFD:

> **solitary** *adj*
>   following or enjoying a life of solitude: *a solitary disposition*