# Informal word for someone who likes to keep to themselves

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I always thought that **anti-social** describes someone who keeps to themselves. But according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-social_behaviour), anti-social is not the right word. What, then, is the correct word to describe someone who prefers to keep to themselves, avoids parties and get-togethers? I'm not looking for the absolutely precise medical term for a mental illness (because such behavior may not in fact be an illness), just an informal word.

Example:
- Where is John? Is he going out with us for dinner?
- Nah, he's probably watching Netflix in his room. He tends to be [      ].

**Addendum**
When most people say *anti-social* in an informal context, are just referring to someone keeping to themselves, or are they in fact suggesting their conscience is in question (which is a symptom of the Antisocial Personality Disorder)?

Comment: Introvert? Lone wolf?

Comment: One question per post is the policy of Stack Exchange. Please delete the addendum and post a separate question if you want. But remember you have to include your own research efforts in a question. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: I've never heard *anti-social* by itself being used in a clinical sense - only in A-S PD. Anti-social is a (tiny) (little) bit stronger than "likes to keep to themselves" and has a tiny hint of condemnation/disapproval - but barely noticable and could refer to local rather than global characteristic.

Comment: Related question, [What is a word for someone who prefers to be lonely?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267863/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-prefers-to-be-lonely).

Comment: @Rathony thanks for letting me know about the guidelines. It looks like there are quite a few answers addressing the secondary question, so deleting it may be a little late for me at this point. I'll keep this in mind in the  future though. And thanks for the question link.

Comment: @A.S. What do you mean by local and global characteristics? Does it mean it applies to this person only at a specific time rather than something chronic?

Comment: Yes. Non-clinically it is frequently used in the local sense. Here is google's second meaning: not sociable; not wanting the company of others.
synonyms: unsociable, unfriendly, uncommunicative, reclusive, withdrawn, avoidant; *informal* standoffish
"I'm feeling a bit antisocial".

Comment: antisocial really means when someone has sociopathic tendencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Loner

[Merriam Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loner) definition of loner:

> loner, noun | lon·er | \ˈlō-nər\ :  one that avoids others; especially :  individualist

---

Personally, I have found that **anti-social**, while sounding technical, is used far more in the sense of being a loner.

> Why doesn't my son want to play ball with the other kids? He's so ***anti-social.*** What will I ever do?

Comment: Thank you - this is great. Would you mind weighing in on the added question in regards to the usage of anti-social?

Comment: Nearly synonymous: **hermit**.

Comment: @Scott Definition-wise, it is indeed similar. However, hermits are generally known to be old, living in the middle of nowhere. Search Google images for "hermit" and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***stick in the mud***

> (*idiomatic, pejorative*) A person unwilling to participate in activities; a curmudgeon or party pooper. *Have a little fun sometimes and don't be such a stick-in-the-mud*. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/stick_in_the_mud)

***homebody***

> A person who prefers pleasures and activities that center around the home; [stay-at-home](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stay-at-home?s=t). [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homebody)

Answer (score 1):

Many learned people use 'anti-social' to refer to those who keep to themselves. But I think in many parts of the world the word is used to refer to criminals. There are many alternative words. Examples:
Don is a private person. He does not attend parties. 
The tribal people are usually unsociable.
The president is media shy. It is difficult to get him talk. 
Kala is an introvert. She lives a solitary life.

Comment: That's because those parts of the world would never say "He is a social person" and would use a word with a different root.

Answer (score 0):

**reclusive** (adjective)

avoiding the company of other people; solitary.