# A noun for chosen loneliness

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word, kind of like loneliness, but without the negative/saddening meaning for describing the act of being alone but preferring it, doing it by a conscious choice.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Very similar: [What is a word for someone who prefers to be lonely?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267863/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-prefers-to-be-lonely) (although that is about a name for the person, and this is about the name of the act itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is [reclusion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reclusion).  A person that makes this choice is a [recluse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recluse?q=reclusion#recluse__89).

EDIT: Reclusion can also mean forced solitary confinement.  [Seclusion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seclusion) also works.  A synonym for recluse is [hermit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hermit).

EDIT: Added links.

Comment: This answer is the right one but please provide some sources for your definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that is captured by [***solitude***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solitude).

> [MASS NOUN] The state or situation of being alone:
>   *she savoured her few hours of freedom and solitude*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/solitude

Comment: This is the obvious choice.

Comment: +1. When Superman chose to be alone, he went to the Fortress of *Solitude*.

Answer (score 1):

How about **hermit**?

According to Merriam-Webster

> **hermit**: a person who lives in a simple way apart from others especially for religious reasons

Comment: +1 Good suggestion. But I think it's [mentioned earlier](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/339439/50044).

Answer (score 0):

You could also describe such a person as a **[loner](https://www.google.com/search?q=loner%20definition&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=)**, or even a "lone wolf."

> a person who prefers not to associate with others.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Not exactly a "real" English word, but it's gaining popularity nonetheless.*</sub>

**Mauerbauertraurigkeit** — [The Dictionary of Obscure Sorrows](http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/post/25422386446/mauerbauertraurigkeit)

> *noun.* The inexplicable urge to push people away, even close friends who you really like—as if all your social tastebuds suddenly went numb, leaving you unable to distinguish cheap politeness from the taste of genuine affection, unable to recognize its rich and ambiguous flavors, its long and delicate maturation, or the simple fact that each tasting is double-blind.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Not exactly single-words, but should work fine.*</sub>

**Alone time** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alone%20time)

> *noun* Time spent by an individual or a couple apart from others.
>
> *"I need some alone time to think things over."*
>   *"We passed many buildings I wanted to explore later, but for now, I just wanted some alone time with Brad."* — Derene Scheeler, Follow Your Heart, 2010

**Me time** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/me-time)

> *mass noun, informal*
>   Time spent relaxing on one’s own as opposed to working or doing things for others, seen as an opportunity to reduce stress or restore energy.
>
> *"schedule some me time when you get home."*
>   *"Juggling business, family fun and a little me time just got easier!"*
>   *"But what do rock stars do when they need to get away from the band and secure a little me time?"*

Answer (score 0):

More context should be given I think to your question. A temporary withdrawal can be a *retreat*, while a partial but enduring choice of reduced interactions could be an *independent* or *self-sufficient* attitude.